# How do I access the current location (lat, lng) of a map marker using ngMap in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have an Angularjs website that requests geolocation from users using [ngMap](http://ngmap.github.io/). Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQylfJp3O4jsJfWVKFwf?p=preview).

```
<map center="current-location" zoom="16">
  <marker visible="true" centered="true" position="current-location" title="You are Here" draggable="true"></marker>
</map>
```

It works fine but how can I access (save or print) the current location or the marker's location after it's been dragged to a different place?

Comment: is my solution working for you ?

Comment: @macrog your solution solves it in a different way so I can't find a better solution, I'll go with your solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to access a marker's location (lat, lng).

```js
$scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, evtMap) {
    $scope.map = evtMap;
  });

  $scope.showMarkerLatlng = function(){
    alert($scope.map.markers[0].getPosition());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not exaclty a workin solution for you question but hopefully will get you closer to what you need. Please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kScjLcwSz7gGtgmRzmbA?p=preview).

When clicking on a map you are creating a marker and showing it's position.

```
$scope.placeMarker = function(e) {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: e.latLng, map: map});
      $window.alert("position: " + e.latLng);

      map.panTo(e.latLng);
    }
```

Hope it helps.